# Send email through nodemailer nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodemailer

First I am checking the email present in the database, if present then it will generate the hashcode and after that it will update the database and once the hashcode is generated then email will be send to the user. So I am stuck how to send email please any help.

```
    const md5 = require('md5');
    let transporter = require("../config/transporter");
    
    export const newemail = async(req,res ) => {
    try{
        var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        const user = await db.findOne('USER', { email: req.body.email });
        res.status(200).json(user);
    
        if (!re.test(req.body.email)) {
            res.json('Email address is not valid!');
        } else {
            const email = req.body.email;
            const name = email.substring(0, email.lastIndexOf("@"));
            const domain = email.substring(email.lastIndexOf("@") +1);
            const hashCode = md5(name + domain);
            function sendingMail(referredBy){
          
            const user = await db.findOneandUpdate('USER', { email: req.body.email, referralCode: hashCode, referredBy: referredBy }); 
          const email = user.email;
          console.log(email + "email");
               //send verification mail

               let mailOptions = {
                from: 'xxyyzz@gmail.com', // sender address
                to: email, // list of receivers
                subject: settingsConfig.subjectLine, // Subject line
                text: settingsConfig.message, // plaintext body
                html: settingConfig.message // html body
            };
            console.log("MAILING!");
        console.log(mailOptions)
        // send mail with defined transport object
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error);
            }
            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        });
         };

    }
}
       catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
    }

}
```

Please anyone how to move further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const md5 = require('md5');
let transporter = require("../config/transporter");


export const sendEmail = async (to, from, subject, body) => {
    // use any mailer library to send the email
}

export const isValidEmail = async (email) => {
    const regex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}

export const findUserByEmail = async (email) => {
    // db instance
    return await db.findOne('USER', { email });
}

export const generateHash = async (email) => {
    const name = email.substring(0, email.lastIndexOf("@"));
    const domain = email.substring(email.lastIndexOf("@") +1);
    return md5(name + domain);
}



export const verifyAndEmail = async(req,res ) => {
try{
    // var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    // const user = await db.findOne('USER', { email: req.body.email });
    // res.status(200).json(user);
    // step-1 destructure email from request body
    const {
        email
    } = req.body;

    // step-2, validate the email id
    const isEmailValid = await isValidEmail(email);

    if(!isEmailValid) {
        throw new Error('Invalid email');
        // return appropiate response
    }

    // step-3 find a user by email
    const user = await findUserByEmail(email);

    // step-4 validate, if user does not exists
    if (!user) {
        throw new Error('User does not exist');
        // return appropiate response
    }

    //step-5 generate the hash using user's email
    const hash = await generateHash(email);

    // step-6, call send email method with the parameters
    }
       catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
    }

}
```

```html
I would suggest, you should refactor your code to following. 

Run it and let me know if you face any issues. 


This approach will help you to debug the error.
```

Comment: Thanks @Harsh Srivastava:. I will let you know about this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you on linkedin? @HarshSrivastava:

Comment: yes

https://www.linkedin.com/in/harsh-srivastava/

Comment: where should I add         `        const user = await db.findOneandUpdate('USER', { email: req.body.email, referralCode: hashCode, referredBy: referredBy }); `  @Harsh Srivastava